# Android database version in configuration file

Tags: android, xml, configuration

Is it possible to keep the version of database of an Android app in any configuration xml e.g. Strings.XML ; instead of keeping it as variable in SQLiteOpenHelper subclass.

Atleast is it possible to read from such XML when class is loaded.

e.g.

```
public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION =   /// Some code to initialize version from config file
:
:
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to keep it in the xml file?

Comment: You can try. I suggest you to put it in `/res/values/integers.xml`. But it's an overhead, since you have to read it from there, while a static constant is an inexpensive code bit.

Comment: @Blackbelt I want to keep it in XML file so that I do not need to touch Java code. It is preferred practice to keep configuration; environment values; properties etc. out of code. So that one does not touch code while changing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get database version using

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.getVersion()
```

It returns an `int` value representing database version.

It's using `PRAGMA user_version` statement to read that version. For more information you can use `setVersion()`, in order to set version of database

Comment: I do not want to get the version of existing database. It is for configuration change so that onUpgrade() is triggered whenever I increment the version.